# how do i build gcc on a mac?

Tags: c++, macos, gcc, c++11

I'd like to build the latest version of gcc on a mac. I have the latest xcode but I'm looking for some of the c++0x features that are in more recent versions (the lambda functions, etc).

Are there any good step-by-step tutorials on doing this?

Comment: Yet another option:
https://github.com/kennethreitz/osx-gcc-installer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One option is to install [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org/) and install the `gcc46` package:

```
sudo port install gcc46
```

Another option is to download the source code and build it as follows:

```
tar xzvf gcc-4.6.0.tar.gz
cd gcc-4.6.0
./configure
make
```

Note that GCC 4.6.0 requires as prerequisites [GMP](http://gmplib.org/) 4.2+, [MPFR](http://www.mpfr.org/) 2.3.1+, and [MPC](http://www.multiprecision.org/) 0.8.0+.  If `./configure` fails, it's probably because you're missing one of these (though it should give you a helpful error message in any case).

Building will take a while—likely several hours, depending on your hardware.

Answer (score 10):

You should look at the [Homebrew project](https://brew.sh/).

Homebrew allows you to do things like this:

```
brew install gcc
```

[Mac homebrew installation instructions are available here.](https://github.com/Homebrew/legacy-homebrew)

Comment: Brew installations of gcc are more tricky than that, see the wiki page here https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/wiki/Custom-GCC-and-cross-compilers for details.

Comment: You cannot install gcc by `brew install gcc` . At least it doesn't work on my machine. as mentioned by @Berkus `brew install https://github.com/adamv/homebrew-alt/raw/master/duplicates/gcc.rb` should work.

Comment: brew install https://github.com/adamv/homebrew-alt/raw/master/duplicates/gcc.rb   did it for me thx a lot but now I get: checking whether the C compiler works... no in the log and ruby install fails then.

Answer (score 8):

Add GCC support to a **fresh Xcode 4.2 installation** using this homebrew formula:

```
brew install https://raw.github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-dupes/master/apple-gcc42.rb
```

Upgrading from Xcode 4.1 doesn't drop existing GCC support, so this formula is only useful if you're working with a fresh 4.2+ installation.

Comment: Update as of April 2013:  Brew builds various versions of gcc pretty
well now.  To install the latest gcc:  
    `brew install gcc48`
That version of gcc will be accessible at  `/usr/local/bin/gcc-4.8`
I use  
    `export CC=gcc-4.8` before running `./configure` to choose that compiler.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest building it yourself (Adam details how to do so). This will give you fine control on where to install and all the options you want to select. My experience from having multiple versions of gcc is that, if care is not taken apple's version of gcc can be damaged.

To speed up gcc installation you might want to look at --enable-languages option. If there are languages you don't need installed with the new gcc then you may not want to select them.