# Compile C++11 code on mac?

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm new to C++11. I've tried:

`clang++ -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ *.cc`

It works, but my questions is:

1. Is there anyway to set these flag as default for clang++?
2. How to update g++ 4.2 to a version that supports C++11?
3. Which way do you think it's the best to compile C++11 code on mac?

Thanks.

Comment: _"Is there anyway to set these flag as default for clang++?"_ - Couldn't you just add this flag to _project options in your IDE_ / _CMake_ / _any other build system configuration file_ instead?

Comment: So what was it with your null pointer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Outside of an IDE (e.g., in shell), I normally have the variable `CXX` set to: `"clang -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++"` in `.profile` / `.tcshrc` / etc., since this is picked up by most configure scripts too. On the cmd line I might use: `$CXX -c foo.cc`

MacPorts gcc-4.8.1 works well: `"[sudo] port install gcc48 [-universal]"`

`"[sudo] port select --set gcc gcc48"` will make this the default `gcc`, `g++`, etc.

Don't attempt to update or modify the system tools, like the old gcc-4.2 / llvm hybrid that comes with Xcode.

I don't know what you mean by 'best' way in the 3rd part of your question, but with Apple's support (they employ the primary author of LLVM), and other projects like FreeBSD behind it, clang will only continue to improve. It's already *much* faster than gcc, has far better error messages / diagnostics (especially for C++ and templates), and a modular architecture. For OS X, it's the clear choice.

Answer (score 6):

Brett has described how to install GCC it with MacPorts. Here’s how to do it with [Homebrew](http://mxcl.github.io/homebrew/), which styles itself (rightfully!) as a modern replacement of MacPorts:

```
brew tap homebrew/versions
brew install --enable-cxx gcc48
```

As far as I know the easiest way to install the most recent Clang is by downloading the compiled version linked in dsign’s answer – and, as Brett mentioned, since Apple uses clang internally it’s not advised to tinker with that installation – just put yours somewhere else.

Concerning what the “best” compiler is there are two things to consider in addition to what Brett has already said:

1. GCC is much older and more *mature* than Clang. Internal compiler errors do happen occasionally in Clang. That said, it’s maturing rapidly because it’s being pushed by several companies.
2. Clang is feature complete for C++11, [GCC 4.8 is not](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/status.html#status.iso.2011). One very obvious example of this is the fact that GCC 4.8 still has no working `<regex>` implementation, which is a shame.

Comment: I've simply been too lazy to give Homebrew a try. One thing about MacPorts that's been annoying me lately is the inability to install (build) a port from source in many cases, despite a correct setup, latest Xcode, etc.

Comment: http://www.h-online.com/open/news/item/GCC-4-8-1-is-C-11-feature-complete-1875093.html

Comment: @manasij7479 That news item is wrong, and my answer already contains the reason why. The *compiler* may be feature complete but their standard library implementation isn’t.

Comment: Okay..so care to give me some <regex> code that doesn't work ? I remember trying simple tutorials and everything worked.

Comment: @manasij7479 You must misremember. Nothing works, not even minimal examples: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=a6bc1d6515491e6c95c50375657cc8b8-50d9cfc8a1d350e7409e81e87c2653ba, and the GCC website says so quite explicitly: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/status.html#status.iso.2011

Comment: You are right. I might have used clang. Is boost.regex a drop in replacement for GCC ?

Comment: @manasij7479 Yes it is. In fact I’m puzzled that the GCC maintainers didn’t simply put the Boost implementation into their library implementation, at least temporarily. After all, they did this with other parts (e.g. `shared_ptr`).

Answer (score 1):

Answers:

1. I don't think so
2. You install another g++ version alongside 4.2, it is bad karma to remove the one that comes with the system. To install a new one, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6210399/how-do-i-build-gcc-on-a-mac)
3. Same goes for clang. You can download it [here](http://llvm.org/releases/3.3/clang+llvm-3.3-x86_64-apple-darwin12.tar.gz).

In general, I totally recommend that you get better g++ compilers, 4.2 is quite old and its code quality is not as good. And using c++ 11 is totally worth it.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Right! Your solution however doesn't look as foolproof as having a system-wide configuration setting for the c++ compiler somewhere, which again, would be a very bad idea for bad-ass legacy programs that *need* to be compiled without C++ 11 (why would that happen?). So, my working advice to anybody would be "don't be lazy and mind the flag" anyway.

Comment: The guys from the Lounge<C++> chat room here on Stack Overflow would like a word with you. In fact, with a bit of care putting the flag as default isn’t a problem. If you are compiling legacy software you can simply reset the relevant environment variables.

Answer (score 1):

Do it all in Xcode's build settings like most Apple developers. Xcode simplifies life in many ways.